# installing mac to an usb pen, using windows?

Tags: windows, mac, usb, installation

Is it possible to install mac to an usb pen?

I'm using a windows, and want to dual-boot mac, but can't create more primary partitions.

Comment: already have 3 primary partitions, wich i believe is maximum, if there is a way to get more I would be interested in that.

Comment: License agreement states you can only install it on Mac hardware. Do you own an Apple thumb drive?

Comment: License agreements and the law governing them are region-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is against the license agreement of the software, but regardless I don't know if your hardware would even be supported by Mac. The range of drivers is very slim, because there aren't many different components in the various models. So, I don't think installing to a pen drive would work, even if you managed to put the data on the drive.